# Why does the second $_GET variable get removed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, get

Okay, so I'm making a website and it uses quite a bit of JQuery and JavaScript because it makes the website easier to use, plus I can use the index page as the page layout and all the other pages to store page data. So here's what I'm doing.

I try to go to the page http://example.com/index?page=ItemSearch?item=Sword&sortby=Damage

but as soon as the page loads, it removes the last chunk and only loads as http://example.com/index?page=ItemSearch?item=Sword

Here is the code for my page named ItemSearch.php(minus the layout, which in short is just the PHP code):

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
echo $sortby;//I put this in here to see if it would print something as the value, it doesn't.
if(!isset($item)){
echo 'What item are you looking for?<br><br>';
//Form here
}else if(isset($sortby)){//Doesn't recognize that item is or was set because it's no longer there
include('grabdata.php?item='.$item.'&sortby='.$sortby);
echo "Item: ".$item." Sort by ".$sortby;
}else{//Does however notice that the item was set
include('grabdata.php?item='.$item);
echo "Item: ".$item;//Prints "Sword" as it should
}
?>
```

Here is the index page which as I said before is basically just the layout(also shortened in order to remove any personal or un-needed info):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="funcs.js"></script>//JavaScript functions page
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>//Including JQuery in order to use JQuery functions
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
echo '<script>loadPage("' . $page . '");</script>';//Loading whatever the $_GET variable for 'page' is set to, in this case $_GET['page'] = "ItemSearch"
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now of course I should show my JQuery & JavaScript functions so here is my funcs.js file(unedited):

```
function loadPage($link){
$('#content').html('<br><br><img src="Load.gif"/>');//Shows a loading bar so people know the page is loading
$('#content').load($link+'.php');//JQuery loads pages onto the #content div
window.history.pushState("", "", '/index?page='+$link);//If I comment this line out, it does not remove the second $_GET variable from the address bar... However the website still does not recognize that the second $_GET variable is there? Idk why :/
}

function loadTitle($link){
$(document).attr('title', "Website name here - "+$link);//Just changes the name of the page
}
```

I don't really understand why it is completely removing the second $_GET variable, nor do I understand why it doesn't recognize it when it is there. Hopefully the comment shown above will help some. I would really appreciate any help I can possibly get. Thank you!

Comment: There's two `?` in your query string. Typo?

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  Are you describing a client-side or a server-side issue?  Please remove the (in)appropriate language tags and code snippets accordingly...

Comment: As an aside, this is absolutely terrible for SEO. Spider's don't use javascript, so they would never get any info when they crawl your pages. Also, any non-JS users would see ...nothing...

Comment: @Machavity No, what page is equal to is the actual page. So the page is ItemSearch?item=Sword&sortby=Damage

Comment: @ahren That does not matter, and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth There is no inappropriate language in the tags, or code snippets. I believe it's server-sided.

Comment: @user3047535: But you should be able to confirm this by looking at the generated source code in your browser.  Either unexpected code has been generated (in which case it's a problem with your PHP), or the expected code has been generated (in which case it's a problem with your JS/HTML).  So you should be able to halve the problem (and thus halve your question) in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm pretty sure there's no problem with the PHP, just the JQuery and probably my HTAccess but I don't know what the problem is and I don't know how to thin out the possibilities because I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: One approach is to incrementally simplify the situation, i.e. by incrementally removing all code not related to the problem, and re-running.

Comment: I've just confirmed that the issue is not with the PHP. Here are the URL's of the pages I used: (PHP only page) http://halo.strickensoftworks.com/roster?clan=CuddlyCriminals&sortby=kdr , (JQuery and PHP) http://halo.strickensoftworks.com/index?page=roster?clan=CuddlyCriminals&sortby=kdr . It will tell you which $_GET variables it reads as set when it loads the page.

Comment: If the `page` should have the entire string `ItemSearch?item=Sword&sortby=Damage` as a value is should be urlencoded: `ItemSearch%3Fitem%3DSword%26sortby%3DDamage`. Whether or not this is what you want, at this point, your current url is just syntactically incorrect / invalid, and all bets are off at that point. There's little need to check in code for problems if that problem is staring you in the face.

Comment: So... `window.history.pushState("", "", '/index?page=' + encodeURIComponent($link));`

Comment: @Wrikken Wow, you're a life saver. Give this person a medal! <3
Thanks, I really appreciate it. I wish I knew as much as you, but I'm really only doing this as a hobby. Again thanks a lot. You really helped me out here.

Comment: @Wrikken for some reason, that line is still removing the second $_GET variable from the address bar though. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Well, you whole `loadPage` function isn't meant for get variable addition... What is this `.php` addition, which would make the URL `ItemSearch?item=Sword&sortby=Damage.php`?

Comment: Are you guys sure this is not a UrlRewrite issue? it seems a Rewrite could get rid of any parameters after the ampersand. I would provide more help but I have to leave now T_T